# Have installed sublime text 2 but can't access exercism exercises on it via command line instructions

Tags: bash, installation

I watched the you tube video for the exercism exercise installation (video is titled "Installing the exercism.io command-line client on Mac OS X") I progressed successfully untill the instruction line which Katrina typed as 'subl .' to which my terminal said "command not found."  I was assuming this was because I didn't have the sublime text editor installed, so I installed it onto my computer (dragged the sublime icon into the applications icon) and then typed 'subl .' into terminal  and got the response:  '-bash: subl: command not found' Being a novice to programming I'm not sure what my next step would be.  Any help would be excellent.

Comment: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html

Comment: Thanks Quentin.   Even withyour help it took me goddam forever to work this out, the key for me was right down the bottom  "If you have the MacPorts version of Python installed, then starting Sublime Text 2 via the subl will not work correctly. As a workaround, start Sublime Text 2 first via Finder, and then interact with it using subl."   Cheers